# Meaning of スパークする in 大暴走した言霊がスパークする

Tags: grammar, meaning

I imagine the definition being used is "放電などによって火花が出ること。また、閃光 (せんこう) を発すること" however I am still confused as to what it actually means in this context.

「うかつに口に出せない、秘すべき真の名だよ。**大暴走した言霊がスパークする**レベル」

「しょっちゅう言ってんだろうが」

「あたしはいいの、霊力のステージ的に許されてるから！」

She says "It's a true name that should be kept secret, that cannot be spoken carelessly" and then says it is of the level that "大暴走した言霊がスパークする"

言霊 from my understanding refers to the spiritual power that is thought to be contained within words. 大暴走した modifies 言霊 but what スパークする means in this context is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スパークする  in this context is almost synonymous to (強い光を発しながら)爆発する. She's saying that uttering that word means almost the same thing as casting an explosion spell, because the word itself has an uncontrollably strong power.